# Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: The URL '/posts.index' did not match any routes in your application

Tags: ember.js

i found a thread that I should implment the PostsRoute but I get the error futher. Has anybody an idea?

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
   LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function() {
   // put your routes here
   //this.resource("projects", function() {});
   this.resource('posts', function() {});
   this.resource('projects');
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `posts.index` only gets create if you have sub-routes nested in `posts` (which you don't seem to have according to the code you posted. Try replacing the link to `posts.index` with `posts`.

Comment: I've tried IT with the Nested New Route. But that was the Same issue.

Comment: Could you provide a jsBin?